# How to install mongodb in windows7 64x and how to use with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I want to install mongodb in windows 7(64x) and use with ruby on rails what i do first and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- download [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) itself
- Extract the archive to C:\ by right clicking on the archive and
  selecting Extract All and browsing to C:.

> Example: C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-[version]

- Start the **Command Prompt** by selecting the **Start Menu**, then
  **All Programs**, then **Accessories**, then right click **Command Prompt**, and select **Run as Administrator** from the popup menu. In
  the **Command Prompt**, issue the following commands:

> ```
> cd \
> move C:\mongodb-win32-* C:\mongodb
> ```

- MongoDB requires a data folder to store its files. The default
  location for the MongoDB data directory is C:\data\db. Create this
  folder using the Command Prompt. Issue the following command
  sequence:

> ```
> md data
> md data\db
> ```

- Start MongoDB To start MongoDB, execute from the Command Prompt:

> C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe

[source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)